# Checking IP Port State Remotely

Tags: c#, tcp, remoting, udp, ip

I found an article on getting active tcp/udp connections on a machine.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx

My issue however is I need to be able to determine active connections remotely - to see if a particular port is running or listening without tampering with the machine.

Is this possible?

Doesn't seem like it natively, otherwise it could pose a security issue. The alternative would be to query a remoting service which could then make the necessary calls on the local machine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

[Nmap](http://nmap.org) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to know which ports are open without the remote computer knowing it.  But you can determine the information without the program running on the port knowing it (i.e. without interfering with the program).

**Use SYN scanning:**

To establish a connection, TCP uses a three-way handshake.  This can be exploited to find out if a port is open or not without the program knowing.

The handshake works as follows:

1. The client performs an active open by sending a SYN to the server.
2. The server replies with a SYN-ACK.
3. Normally, the client sends an ACK back to the server.  But this step is skipped.

> SYN scan is the most popular form of
>   TCP scanning. Rather than use the
>   operating system's network functions,
>   the port scanner generates raw IP
>   packets itself, and monitors for
>   responses. This scan type is also
>   known as "half-open scanning", because
>   it never actually opens a full TCP
>   connection. The port scanner generates
>   a SYN packet. If the target port is
>   open, it will respond with a SYN-ACK
>   packet. The scanner host responds with
>   a RST packet, closing the connection
>   before the handshake is completed.
>
> The use of raw networking has several
>   advantages, giving the scanner full
>   control of the packets sent and the
>   timeout for responses, and allowing
>   detailed reporting of the responses.
>   There is debate over which scan is
>   less intrusive on the target host. SYN
>   scan has the advantage that the
>   individual services never actually
>   receive a connection while some
>   services can be crashed with a connect
>   scan. However, the RST during the
>   handshake can cause problems for some
>   network stacks, particularly simple
>   devices like printers. There are no
>   conclusive arguments either way.

[Source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner)

As is mentioned below, I think [nmap](http://nmap.org/) can do SYN scanning.

**Using sockets for TCP port scanning:**

One way to determine which ports are open is to open a socket to that port.  Or to a different port which finds out the information for you like you mentioned.

For example from command prompt or a terminal:

```
telnet google.com 80
```

**UDP Port scanning:**

if a UDP packet is sent to a port that is not open, the system will respond with an ICMP port unreachable message. You can use this method to determine if a port is open or close.  But the receiving program will know.

Comment: The problem with connecting to the socket directly is that it will interfere with any existing program running on the port. 

I'm trying to determine the state of a port - which in turn will let me know if a program is running correctly.

Comment: I believe nmap can tell if there is a program listening on a port without completing the three-way handshake. So, it wont interfere with  the program running on that port because it never notices a connection.

Answer (score 1):

[neouser99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124638/checking-ip-port-state-remotely#124643) (et al) has suggested [NMAP](http://nmap.org/). NMAP is very good if all you're trying to do is to detect ports that are open on the remote machine.

But from the sounds of your question you're actually trying to determine what ports are both open *and* connected on your remote machine. If you're after a general monitoring solution, including the connected ports, then you could install an snmp server on your remote machine. There are two [MIBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base) that let you check for port status which are [TCP-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4022)::tcpConnectionTable and [UDP-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4113)::udpEndpointTable.

The daemon (server) supplied in [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) has most likely got support for these mibs.